# How to call a function with a TreeNode pointer as parameter in main, C++

Tags: c++

I have a function getHeight(TreeNode< NODETYPE > *root)
in a class and in the main I want to find the value let's say 12 in a tree.
How do would I call the function in main for e.g like
getHeight(12); or getHeight(&12) or getHeight(*12), none of these 
will work, does anyone know how to call the function?

Comment: A function named `getHeight` sounds like it would return the height of a tree, and would have nothing to do with values contained therein. What makes you believe it's a suitable function to call in order to find a given value? The fact that it does not actually accept a value as a parameter should be telling you something.

Comment: Instantiate the class and call the method. `12` is not a `TreeNode` it's an integer literal. Maybe search the tree for the value first.

Comment: Assuming that 'getHeight(TreeNode* root)' returns the height of the tree with the root pointer pointing to the root node of the tree, first instantiate the tree using the tree class. Then, add a root node by creating instantiating node class and add it to the tree. Then, after adding required number of nodes in the tree, call your getHeight() function with its argument as your root node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass pointer to the Node in the tree to get the height of that node like,

```
NODETYPE *node = <get a node from wherever possible>
int height = getHeight(node);
```